# Symfony @Paramconverter and entity update through FormType fail

Tags: php, forms, symfony-2.7

I am building an REST API with Symfony 2.7.2, using Doctrine, FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle. I was creating controller for my Address class using [this pattern](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/).

My Problem is that using default id->entity ParamConverter and passing converted Entity to a form type for updating it causes tha validation to fail as shown below. BUT if i replace it with an old-school $id and I fetch the entity myself from repository, it works fine.

Is it bug or have I missed something?

Relevant code follows.

So I have a controller method for get (HTTP GET) entity by id:

```
/**
 * @Route("addresses/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="base_address_entity")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function detailAction(Address $address)
{
    return $address;
}
```

(*works fine*)

Another action for create new entity (HTTP POST)

```
/**
 * @Route("addresses")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function insertAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->processForm(new Address(), $request);
}
```

(*also works fine*)

..and an update action (HTTP PUT), using default id ParamConverter as in the DetailAction:

```
/**
 * @Route("addresses/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="base_address_create")
 * @Method({"PUT"})
 */
public function updateAction(Address $address, Request $request)
{
    return $this->processForm($address, $request);
}
```

*and this one fails with an unspecified form error*:

```
"code": 400,
"message": "Validation Failed",
"errors": {
    "errors": [
        "This value is not valid."
    ],
    "children": {
        ...no errors in any of the of the other fields
```

The process form function is the same for both *insertAction* and *updateAction*:

```
public function processForm(Address $address, Request $request)
{
    /** @var AddressRepository $addressRepository */

    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('address.form_type'), $address);

    $form->submit($request->get($form->getName()));

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $addressRepository = $this->get('address.repository');
        $addressRepository->save($address);
        return $this->get('success');
    }
    return $form;
}
```